# SQL Server : select results where the total is equal a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select which returns the following output:

```
Percent Sales  |   Brand
---------------+-------------
30.12              BMW
29.11              Honda
22.12              Daimler
06.90              Mercedes
02.11              VW
00.12              Ford
```

The output should be the brands, which are making the top 80 percent income.

So in this case it would be the first 3 rows.

Comment: Which dbms you are using ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Which version 2008,2012,2014..?

Comment: This: _where the total of all rows exceed the 80%_ is unclear. In fact, it sounds like a complete nonsense to me

Comment: Also do you have any column to order the results when summing up.

Comment: I try to explain it again: the output should be the brands, which are making  the top 80 percent income. I hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering there is a `Id` column to order the results. You need to find running total

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Sum([Percent Sales])OVER(ORDER BY id) AS run_tot
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Min(CASE WHEN run_tot > 80 THEN run_tot END) OVER() min_run_tot
        FROM   cte) a
WHERE  run_tot <= min_run_tot
ORDER  BY id
```

or as mentioned in comments if you want to order the result in `[Percent Sales] desc` then

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Sum([Percent Sales])OVER(ORDER BY [Percent Sales] desc) AS run_tot
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Min(CASE WHEN run_tot > 80 THEN run_tot END) OVER() min_run_tot
        FROM   cte) a
WHERE  run_tot <= min_run_tot
ORDER  BY id
```

Comment: can also be `order by [Percent Sales] desc` i guess if there were no `id` column.

Comment: @vkp - I didn't use it because OP said first 3 rows. If we use `[Percent Sales]` then it will not be first three rows

Comment: ..sorry.. it should've been the descending order